# Store element text in Appim wd.js

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, appium

I'm new to [Appium](http://appium.io/) and I'm trying to make use of this [workshop Git project](https://github.com/appium/javascript-workshop), which relies on [wd.js](https://github.com/admc/wd) and [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). As far as I saw in the docs and posts there are two ways to access the text of some native element in my [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) specs.

First:

```
it('should be able to do stuff', function (done) {
    this.driver
      .elementsByClassName('android.widget.EditText').at(0)
        .sendKeys('Test')
        .text().should.eventually.equal('Test')
      .nodeify(done);
  });
```

Second:

```
it('should be able to do stuff', function (done) {
  this.driver
    .waitForElementByCss("#my-id" , 2000, function(err, el) {
    el.text(function(err, text) { text.should.equal('Test'); });
    })
  .nodeify(done);
});
```

What is the way of storing any found element's text in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = this.driver
  .elementByClassName('android.widget.EditText')
    .text();
```

Where `.elementByClassName()` returns an element according to search criteria and `.text()` returns the text value of that element.

See the API documentation of wd.js for all existing driver commands: https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md

Comment: Can you please provide a working snippet? This was the *very* first thing I've tried, even without reading their docs. The value of the ````text```` is ````{ status: pending }````

Comment: A little late to the party, but what you have there is a promise.  You'll need to wait for it to resolve.  Try adding a `text.then()` with a function to call when it resolves.

Answer (score 0):

```
it('should be able to do stuff', function (done) {
driver.waitForElementByClassName("#my-class" , 2000)
.then(function(el){
 el.text().should.equal('Test');
 done();
 )}
});
```

This is how I do it in Appium+wd.js+mocha